# libav - avcodec_video_encode2() + fwrite() = non functional files

Tags: c, decode, encode, libav

I can't seem to get anything useful out of the AVPacket.data I'm writing. It's not generating valid video files and they're *incredibly* small. 4Mb converts to ~300Kb. They're not playing and VLC reports their formats as "undf" (missing headers?). I'm stuck and need some help moving on.

Here's the decode-encode snippet:

```
// initialize the output context
ctx_out = avformat_alloc_context();

// guess container format
ctx_out->oformat = av_guess_format(NULL, out_file_name, NULL);
snprintf(ctx_out->filename, sizeof(ctx_out->filename), "%s", out_file_name);

// .. stripped: creates video stream, encoder and its codec

if ((res = avio_open2(&ctx_out->pb, out_file_name, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE, NULL, NULL)) != 0) {
  callback_with_error(options, "Failed to open output file for writing (%s)", res);
  return;
}

if ((res = avformat_write_header(ctx_out, NULL)) != 0) {
  callback_with_error(options, "Failed to write output format header (%s)", res);
  return;
}

av_init_packet(&packet);
while (av_read_frame(ctx_format, &packet) >= 0) {
  frame_finished = 0;
  total_size    += packet.size;

  if (packet.stream_index == video_stream) {
    len = avcodec_decode_video2(decoder_video, frame, &frame_finished, &packet);

    if (len < 0) {
      callback_with_error(options, "Frame #%d video decoding error (%d)", current_frame, len);
      return;
    }

    if (frame_finished) {
      len = avcodec_encode_video2(encoder_video, &packet, frame, &frame_finished);

      if (len < 0) {
        continue; // dropped?
      }

      if (frame_finished) {
        if ((res = av_interleaved_write_frame(ctx_out, &packet)) != 0) {
          callback_with_error(options, "Output write error (%d).", res);
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    if (frame_finished) {
      current_frame++;
    }
  } else if (packet.stream_index == audio_stream) {
    // audio
  }
}
av_free_packet(&packet);
av_write_trailer(ctx_out);

for(i = 0; i < ctx_out->nb_streams; i++) {
  av_freep(&ctx_out->streams[i]->codec);
  av_freep(&ctx_out->streams[i]);
}

if (!(ctx_out->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
  avio_close(ctx_out->pb);
}
av_free(ctx_out);
```

I'm hoping there's someone on SO with a bit of knowledge about how LibAV works. I've looked at the examples and read various "articles" about how to use it. So, yeah, I'm stuck for now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you're currently doing here is writing the **raw** content of each video packet to the output file without any sort of container or framing. While this will sort of work for a few special formats (such as MPEG1 video and MP3 audio streams), it does not work in general -- you will need to open up an `AVFormatContext` (using `avformat_write_header`), write each packet to the stream using `av_interleaved_write_frame` (or `av_write_frame` if your stream is already properly interleaved), then tie up all the loose ends using `av_write_trailer`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I came about the av_interleaved_write_frame() shortly after I created this question. I'll update the sample code; it's still no good using those 3.

Comment: Hmm... Any chance you can throw the whole program up as a gist or something so I can have a look? Hard to debug just from this fragment.

Comment: It's a gateway shared library I'm writing. But I've done a "concat" and boiled it all down to pretty much a single function: http://pastebin.com/61hM6jqP

Comment: Wait a minute, what version/fork of libav are you using? `avcodec_encode_video2` doesn't exist in libav 0.8.3.

Comment: I honestly have no idea - is that the problem? I'll check the version when I get to work.

Comment: It's not the problem; it's just getting in the way of me testing the code. If you are using git HEAD, though, I would strongly advise sticking to a released version.

Comment: Turns out I'm using the FFMPEG-"libav" framework. Still, isn't that largely based on libav?

Comment: I got it "working" now. Only this time VLC reports the video as being > 9 hrs long when it should be 34 seconds.